# The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, aws, read-only-database

I am using amazon aurora RDS in my application. I have created cluster endpoint by selecting both read and write instance. Then I used that instance in my application. Whenever I am executing update query I am getting following error:

> The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement".

I have checked online few fixes.

1. Make sure you are using cluster end point - Yes i am using cluster endpoint
2. Read only for mysql is set to 0 - already set.
3. Cluster is pointing to both reader/writer instance.

Comment: Is this flagged as a "replica"?

Comment: how can I check ?